# App creating more than one shortcut on home screen

Tags: java, android, shortcut, launcher, homescreen

My main activity has the following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    …


    homescreenShortcut();
}

private void homescreenShortcut() {
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
    shortcutIntent.setClassName(this, this.getClass().getName());
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "MyApp");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.app_icon));

    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Every time I launch the app, it creates a new shortcut on the home screen. Is there a standard or simple way to make sure only one home icon is created?

I am thinking of uninstalling the previous (if any) and then (re)installing. But that seems like an overkill.

Comment: don't call homescreenShortcut() from on create every time. Make a boolean flag and store it in shared prefs or somewhere that indicates you've made your 1 shortcut, and then wrap the call to `homescreenShortcut()` in an if statement checking that flag. Aside from all of this you really ought not to create shortcuts automatically like this. If the user wants a shortcut they will make one, I think you are likely to annoy more people than you help by doing this auto shortcut thing.

Comment: I agree, you shouldn't do this for the user. Let the user do it for himself. Sorry, but if this happens to me i'd most likely remove the app.

Comment: thanks. But I don't actually get to make the rules. I am working on a project for someone else.

Comment: Use addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

Comment: @juytuyutyuyt when you say `addIntent` do you mean `shortcutIntent` or  `intent` from my code snippet?

Comment: @CoteMounyo sorry for coding missing problem. I mean that it is shortcutIntent

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
```